# Detect when data was inserted/updated to sql

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I have a page named `salesview.php` and `sale.php`. The `salesview.php` is just for preview on a screen connected to a speaker. In the `sale.php` the user can register or update the sales. So what I want is that if the user update or insert a new sale into sql, it will popup a view in `salesview.php` with the users picture, and a song/melody. How can I do this? I think http://salesscreen.com has something similar.

Answer (score -1):

Try using sockets. So if the user enters new data you don't just update the db you update all connected clients by sockets aswell. Just google it it's not that hard. There are many examples with chats ... which is the same principle that you want.

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look at it. The `salesview.php` is not a page the users will use, it will be displayed on a huge screen in the office, which shows attention to the person who registered the sale.

Comment: Doesn't matter ... but if you only want to use it on one client (please don't hit me for that idea) you could implement a scheduler which checks the db ... this is not a good aproach though ... and be sure to only query the last 5 mins or so ... otherwise that would get way out of hand over time